# Meaning of drum TAB notation: horizontal line with upward stroke

Tags: notation, drums, tablature

I came across the following notation which I couldn't find in any guides to drum TAB notation:

[image: "3 Libras" drum part, mm. 27 – 32]

It resembles a small x note lying directly on the 2nd stave line from the top (i.e., a D4 in the treble clef), with a mark above it like a tenuto line but rising up at the end like __/

Any ideas what this means?

For audio reference, this score is from "3 Libras" by A Perfect Circle.

Comment: What does it sound like when you listen to the recording at that point?

Comment: @Tim https://youtu.be/EoqXDPbivFs?t=66 it does indeed sound like a ride cymbal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means to play the cymbal (ride, in this case) on its edge, as opposed to on the bell.

As per the drum guides [at MIT](https://web.mit.edu/merolish/Public/drums.pdf) and [at Online Drummer](https://www.onlinedrummer.com/drum-key/).

**From the MIT guide**

[image: Image of cymbal on edge and on bell notations]

**From the Online Drummer guide**

[image: Image of cymbal crash, edge (tip), and bell notations]

Comment: As an erstwhile drummer, I play ride cymbal on its edge as the usual situation. I'd expect the dots to say otherwise, not the norm.